# How do I modify the configuration file in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a file stat.config -

```
 [stat=1]
 name=value
 name=value

 [stat=2]
 name=value
 name=value
```

And I have a script file scr.sh which is required to update the config file by finding the context and appending data only in the above contexts.

How can this be done ?

Comment: Show you script code.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I like to answer questions as asked, but this time I strongly recommend you **do not use a shell script for this**.  Shell scripts are good for simple tasks, but they are delicate.  If there is a bug in your script you will delete or corrupt your config file.

Better to use a more powerful language like Python, Perl or Ruby.  Python's [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html) library seems to do exactly what you want.  If I am reading the docs correctly, you can do:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.ini')

config['stat2']['flame'] = "42"

with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
     config.write(configfile)
```

The nice thing about this is that if the program fails while you are editting `config`, then nothing will be written, so there is less danger of currupting your file.

The other languages I named probably have equally good solutions.

Comment: But i am required to do it the way i posted here ...

Comment: In what sense is it "required"?  Is it a homework assignment for shell scripting?  For most practical situations, Python and Perl interpreters will be available wherever there is a shell.  If you really can't use these languages, then I suggest you use "awk" which has become a de-facto shell Extension.

Comment: yes its an assignment ... i m trying hard but cannot find a solution

Comment: OK: first ask your tutor if it is OK to embed an awk or python script into you program.  *IF* you  can't, then scan through the file using `read` and the somehow figure out whether your line is an assignment or a Header.  If it is a header, check if it is the "right" section.  If so, insert your new line.  For all other cases just copy the input text to the output text.  I think it will be ugly.

Comment: i m trying to use sed for finding the [stat=1] and [stat=2] and if found , a newline should get inserted first and then the required name and its value .. but this is getting a li'l hard to implement

Comment: If you are allowed to use "sed" then you are allowed to use "awk".  That will be easier because that is more like a normal language  You can have a pattern that matches your desired header, and when you see that pattern, you output what you want.  For every other line, just copy.